# How to upload image by click on it?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I use Ext.js 6. There is a user's photo on page.
To upload and change photo i use filefield with disabled lable and input. Only button. But how to remove button and upload new image by click on ext.js image container (xtype: "image")?

example fidle

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/qra

task - remove button and do the same by click on image

Comment: Means you want upload functionality on click of image same as button.

Comment: Monhit Saxena, yes you right. I want show open file dialog and upload image to server(ASP.NET MVC). How i can do it by click on image without filefield button